# Angular 2 - Observable update the returned value

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription, angularfire2

How can you update the returned value so it will show when it completes?

It is being called from the html like this:

```
// the item.username is from a higher loop which works.
<div *ngFor="let eqItem of getTest(item.username)">



getTest(username: string): Item[] {
let itemArray: Item[];
this.usersService.subscribeItemsForUsername(username).subscribe(z => {
    itemArray = z;
    //return z;
});
return itemArray;
}
```

Here is the service:

```
  subscribeItemsForUsername(username: string): Observable<Item[]> {
      let returnedList =   this.af.database.list('users', {
        query: {
            orderByChild: 'username',
            equalTo: username,
        }
    });

    return returnedList;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the async pipe

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html#async-pipe

change view to :

```
<div *ngFor="let eqItem of getTest(item.username) | async">
```

and the `getTest` method should return an observable like:

```
getTest(username: string): Observable<Item[]> {
    return this.usersService.subscribeItemsForUsername(username).map(res=> res.json());
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to use 2 pipes at once as I am already using a pipe

Comment: @John of course, just put it after async like `...  | async | anotherPipe`

Answer (score 0):

The function you send as a parameter to the subscribe method is a callback that will called in the future. It may be called after `getTest` method finished his job so your callback will do : `itemArray = z` but `itemArray` is not exsist at this moment.

Thats why the line `<div *ngFor="let eqItem of getTest(item.username)">` in the view is equivalent to `<div *ngFor="let eqItem of []">` (if your callback in the subscribe method will excute after the `getTest` method finished.

Solution:

As @echonax mentioned, `Async` will be the best solution.

```
<div *ngFor="let eqItem of getTest(item.username) | async">

getTest(username: string):Observable<Item[]>{
return this.usersService.subscribeItemsForUsername(username);
}
```

In short: the Async pipe will subscribe and unsubsribe (after the component should be destoryed) and will return to the `ngFor` the array (in this case).

Comment: Is there a way to use 2 pipes at once as I am already using a pipe

Comment: Yes but the additional pipe should get an array (that is what the async pipe will return from `getTest(item.username)` Observable